# How does one seed Entity Framework 7 database?

Tags: entity-framework-core

Is there a proper way to seed a database?

I can't seem to find any document to accomplish this.

Comment: Have a look at the test code to see how it can be done

Answer (score 4):

For now, you'll have to manually seed (however there is [talk of a high level API](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/629) for this in the future).

You can do that like this (assuming you're using ASP.NET 5) in the `Configure` method of the `Startup` class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory logger)
    {
        using (var context = (MyContext) app.ApplicationServices.GetService<MyContext>())
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                //Add seed code here

                context.MyEntity.Add(new MyEntity{ Id = 1 });
                //etc

                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also review the [Music Store](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore) sample application with it's [SampleData](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/master/src/MusicStore/Models/SampleData.cs) class which is a little bit more involved and robust.

Comment: What if you are not using ASP .NET 5?  What options do we have to perform seeding?

Comment: I am talking about EF7 though

Comment: oh, sorry, I misunderstood. You could probably use the `Application_Start` method in `global.asax` or similar.

Comment: Shit..so we do not have seed in EF7?

Answer (score -1):

In the `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)` function in the `Startup` class, add this

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseBrowserLink();
    SeedData.InitializeDatabaseAsync(app.ApplicationServices).Wait();
}
```

And the implementation of the `SeedData.InitializeDatabaseAsync` as below

```
public class SeedData
{
    public static async Task InitializeDatabaseAsync(IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
        bool createUsers = true)
    {
        using (var serviceScope = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            var db = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<SampleDbContext>();
            await db.Database.MigrateAsync();
            using (db)
            {
                await InsertTestData(db);
            }
        }
    }

    private static async Task InsertTestData(SampleDbContextdbContext)
    {
        // seed data here
    }
}
```

The reference of those things above at [here](https://github.com/rowanmiller/UnicornStore/blob/master/UnicornStore/src/UnicornStore/Startup.cs#L66). Hope this help.